# SQL unequal query

Tags: mysql, join

I have this two table:

table1

```
id         column1       column2
1          name1         name2
2          name2         name2
3          name3         name3
4          name4         name4
5          name5         name5
```

table2

```
id         table1_id     column2
1          1             name1
2          3             name3
```

I want to join this two table and get all of the data from `table1` that is not in `table2`. The result should look like this:

```
id         column1       column2
2          name2         name2
4          name4         name4
5          name5         name5
```

I'm asking for what would be the correct sql query.
Thanks.

Comment: get all of the data from table1 that is not in table2 based on which columns?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need join tables here, use NOT EXISTS expression with subquery on table2:

```
select * from table1 t1 where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from table2 where table1_id=t1.id);
```

alternatively you can LEFT JOIN table2 and select rows where table2.id is null:

```
select t1.* from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.table1_id=t1.id
where t2.id is null;
```